# Works of "Longue Durée" history in English

Tags: historiography

According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longue_dur%C3%A9e) on Wikipedia, Longue Durée signifies as approach to writing history that looks at events over an extended period of time, focusing on issues like economics and climate, rather than on the short-term events that tend to accompany standard narrativisations of history. I'm curious as to how such a study might look, but can only find French-languages examples.

Can anybody recommend an English-language example of this style of history writing? I would be especially interested in something touching on mediaeval Europe or on the Ancient Near East, but would also be happy with material that concerns other cultures/regions.

Comment: Maybe some works of *Annales school*?

Comment: Perhaps Wallerstein's "The Modern World System"?

Answer (score 3):

Fernand Braudel's series published by Harper and Row entitled (1) *The Structures of Everyday Life*, (2)*The Wheels of Commerce* and (3) *The Perspective of the World* may fit your needs as they are eurocentric and late medieval to early modern. *The Mediterranean and the Mediterranean World* is his earlier work. Although Braudel was a highly regarded French historian and wrote in his native language the above are English translations.